# How to convert a Map to CSV with java streams efficient?

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to convert a `Map<String, List<String>>` to CSV, where each List should result in one csv line.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map;

String csv = map.stream()
   .map(entry -> entry.values().stream().collect(Collectors.joining(";")))
   .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

Problem: for large lists, this will produce many `String` objects in the intermediate step where the list is joined with `;`.

Question: is it possible to rewrite the above to collect the results into a single efficient `StringBuilder`?

Or should I drop the `stream` approach here and use a simple `for-each` loop, appending the results manually with `StringBuilder.append()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Problem: for large lists, this will produce many String objects in the intermediate step where the list is joined with ;.

This isn't a problem, though. A couple of smallish objects that run 'in context' and effectively turn into garbage almost immediately are 'fast garbage' and usually have virtually no costs associated with them. In light of the fact that this CSV is presumably heading to a disk or network connection, any performance impact of such things are dwarfed.

> single efficient `StringBuilder`?

... Yes. You're using it: `Collectors.joining`.

How have you determined your findings, because they sound suspect. Specifically:

> many String objects

Did your profiler tell you? Are you properly identifying the issue? You *have* a ton of String objects before your code even runs (it's a `Map<String, List<String>>` after all - lots of strings!)

> efficient

A CSV format strongly suggests that this CSV data is heading off-process, either to disk or across a network. Generally inefficiencies in how you transport this data is literally a few thousand times more impactful than inefficiencies in-process, so if you're drawing this conclusion because your code is running slower than you wanted it to, you're looking at the wrong stuff. Look instead at the code that sends this stuff over the network pipe, or onto disk. You didn't paste this code but there are many, many ways to make that quite inefficienct, so presumably, that's your actual problem, **if** you're posting this SO question because your code is running slower than you think it should.

Comment: Actually I did not profile this, but I though using a `StringBuilder` directly to concatenate `String` is *in general* more efficient than any other approach. But you're probably correct that this might be a case of premature optimization.

Comment: Collections.joining _is_ efficient in the exact sense 'StringBuilder is more efficient that general string concatenation' is.

Comment: Build it in the simplest sense that is maintainable.  If the code is later shown to be slow by a profiler you can reconsider your approach at that time.

Comment: But when you’re writing to an external destination anyway, you can use something like `Files.write(path, () -> map.values().stream() .map(v -> v.stream() .collect(Collectors.joining(";"))) .iterator());` which avoids assembling a giant final string in memory. You can even simplify this further, `Files.write(path, () -> map.values().stream() .map(v -> String.join(";", v)) .iterator());`

Comment: @Holger your first snippet does __not__ avoid assembling the giant string. The second one does, but I'd have to take a very wild stab in the dark as to what OP is doing. Instead, in my answer, I highlight how they are likely barking up the wrong tree, instead.

Comment: @rzwitserloot there’s no difference between these two snippets. The absence of `.collect(Collectors.joining("\n"))` is what matters. Instead, `Files.write` will process line by line and use a fixed size buffer. I fully agree with your answer, my suggestions still create a string per line as trying to avoid that wouldn’t gain much.